# Use custom column in Sonata Admin list

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I created a project with Symfony 4.1, and install Sonata Admin Bundle.

In a listing of my categories, I try to add a column which is not related to a field of Category

So I did

```
/* Admin/CategoryAdmin.php */

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('name')
        ->add('test_column', 'string', [
            'template' => 'template_test.html.twig',
        ]);
}
```

And my template.

```
{# templates/template_test.html.twig #}

{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    TEST
{% endblock %}
```

The column is created, but it's empty. What did I do wrong?
Here's my test project: https://github.com/AntoineLemaire/sonata-admin-issue/commits/master

I had a other big project with Symfony 3.4 where it's working with no problem, so I created a fresh projet in 3.4, but I got the same issue.

No error message, juste blank  for my column

---------- EDIT -----------

I had a better look, and it seams that the compiled template does not match my template

[image]

On my old big Symfony3.4 projet, compiled template is the same as template.

But I still don't know why

Comment: I can say that your code is correct. I even checked on my 3.4 project. Currently, I have no clue, gonna check.

Comment: Try with this notation `@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_list_field.html.twig`?

Comment: I was thinking that you were talking about my template_test.html.twig... I've not read enouht.
You're right! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad yceruto said in the comments, the notation of my twig extends was not good:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}
```

instead of

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_list_field.html.twig' %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This ist most likely a path problem. The tricky thing is, that the configureList function won't give you any error (other like in configureForm). It displays the column, tries to match a property in your object but left it empty if there is no property. Double-check your path. I think you are pointing to the wrong file path.

You write

```
{# templates/template_test.html.twig #}
```

but you point to

```
'template' => 'template_test.html.twig',
```

So sonata is looking for `app/Resources/view/template_test.html.twig`

but your comment say its anywhere in `app/Resources/view/templates/template_test.html.twig` or somewhere else.

Comment: In Symfony 4.1, templates are not in `app/Resources/views` but in `/templates/`