# Display of large number with SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm trying to display large number in dataGrid of SonataAdminBundle like this :
*290200920181218*

It's well displayed in my form but not in the dataGrid :

[image: DataGrid Screenshot]

I need to display it without the forcing a specific number format and I have no clue how to force that. There is no special sonataField type for this kind of number or arguments to pass.

**EDIT (@Amira Bedhiafi)**

> Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float")
 *
 * @var float
 */
private $paiementId;
```

> Datagrid:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper) {
        $listMapper->add('paiementId', 'number', array('label' => 'Référence de paiement'))
        ;
    }
```

Comment: It depends on the type of your field.Please check the doc : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html

Comment: Yes i know. It's a float type . But Sonata provide only number typeField

Comment: Create your own type then.

Comment: How ? 
I tried to create a custom template for this field but it's always ignored like here ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51108308/sonata-admin-list-field-template-is-ignored

Answer (score 0):

i didn't find a solution with the float type but in my case i can change for bigDecimal and now it work

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="bigDecimal")
 *
 * @var float
 */
private $paiementId;
```